# Exception when running Jenkins on Windows

Tags: installation, jenkins

I'm trying to install Jenkins-1.464 at the first time as the windows service on Windows 7 64-bit with 32-bit Java. However exception is thrown when I run it.

```
C:\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8082
Running from: C:\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
May 16, 2012 4:48:04 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\Andrey\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
May 16, 2012 4:48:04 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=8082
May 16, 2012 4:48:04 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
May 16, 2012 4:48:04 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:229)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:182)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at Main._main(Main.java:273)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to listen on port 8009
        at winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener.start(Ajp13Listener.java:89)
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:220)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
        at winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener.start(Ajp13Listener.java:84)
        ... 9 more
May 16, 2012 4:48:04 PM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:244)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:43)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:849)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:761)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:217)
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:153)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:191)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I've already tried:

- changing HTTP port through --httpPort command line option
- changing HTTP port through --httpPort argument in jenkins.xml
- turning off Windows firewall

But it doesn't solve the issue.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Issue is solved by running jenkins with `--ajp13Port=-1`. It will disable listener of Apache JServ Protocol v1.3. You can also change port to unused one.

After running `java -jar jenkins.war --ajp13Port=-1 --httpPort=8082` Jenkins started successfully and is accessible through `http://localhost:8082/`

Comment: This worked for me. I installed Jenkins on a box where we run the Solr search engine with Apache/Tomcat. Tomcat was bound to port 8009 for the AJP/1.3 connector.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the most useful message was:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to listen on port 8009
```

As you probably know, this is the typical Apache JServ Protocol AJP Connector port.

Running `netstat -ano` I found that another process was listening on this port instead of Jenkins.  In my case a colleague had installed YouTrack and that service had been started before Jenkins.  This made Jenkins unhappy.

I stopped the YouTrack service, started Jenkins and then restarted YouTrack and everyone was happy.

Answer (score 2):

update jenkins.xml   to

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war"  --ajp13Port=-1 --httpPort=8082</arguments>
```